# Bootstrap, how to align all image on the center?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Currently my grid image were aligned like this

[image]

But my goal is to make the grid image like this, notice the "img 1" were aligned on the center. How to achieve this?

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row imagetiles">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <img src=https://i.imgur.com/nXSiWbw.jpg class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <img src=https://i.imgur.com/0dXOdvZ.jpg class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <img src=https://i.imgur.com/nXSiWbw.jpg class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <img src=https://i.imgur.com/0dXOdvZ.jpg class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.imagetiles div.col-lg-3.col-md-3.col-sm-3.col-xs-6{
  padding: 0px;
}
```

[jsfiddle can be view here](https://jsfiddle.net/0udbmec2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the Bootstrap 4 way to do so.

You can just add `d-flex align-items-center` class to the `row`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row imagetiles d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 p-0">
            <img src=https://i.imgur.com/nXSiWbw.jpg class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 p-0">
            <img src=https://i.imgur.com/0dXOdvZ.jpg class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 p-0">
            <img src=https://i.imgur.com/nXSiWbw.jpg class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 p-0">
            <img src=https://i.imgur.com/0dXOdvZ.jpg class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, you used an incorrect version of Bootstrap 4 in your initial JSFiddle. Updated to the latest version at this moment. Also, the jQuery version used is also incorrect (you should notice an error in Developer Console).

To set a particular DIV to have zero padding, you can use Bootstrap layout help class `p-0`; you don't need to set it specifically in CSS.

Last, `img-responsive` is for Bootstrap 3, `img-fluid` is for Bootstrap 4. Don't mix them up.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/bq8covg5/7/

Answer (score 2):

Change your CSS to:

```
div.imagetiles div.col-lg-3.col-md-3.col-sm-3.col-xs-6{
  padding: 0px;
  align-self: center;
}
div.imagetiles{
  display: flex;
}
```

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/dfg65hpx/)'s the jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this to your CSS:

```
.imagetiles {
 align-items: center;
 display: flex;
}
```

jsfiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/7snfxL4d/

Comment: Working, but not in Bootstrap way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different approaches but the flex one is really easy like this :

```
.imagetiles{
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to add class `my-auto` to your img tag
2. If 1st dont work try to make the whole row a flex-wrap with classes `d-flex align-content-center flex-wrap`

You can find more [here](https://medium.com/wdstack/bootstrap-4-vertical-center-1211448a2eff).

Comment: hmmm seems like both doesnt work on my jsfiddle

Comment: Are you sure that you implement bootstrap right? Because if I add simple class in jsfiddle bootstrap isnt working like it should

Comment: Hi both, the initial JSFiddle has JS error due to incorrect version of jQuery. Please check Developer Console